# print strings of one dataframe contained in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, string-matching

I have two dataframes:
one dataframe consists of two columns ('good' and bad')
and another one that contains text data.

```
df_dictionary = pd.DataFrame({'good': ['love', 'like'],
                    'bad': ['dislike', 'hate']})
df_text = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['i love cats', 'i hate dogs']})
```

Now I would like to retrieve exact string matches of words that are in the dictionary and are contained in col1 of df_text and assign the string match to the second column of df_text.

I tried `.isin()`, however this code only shows exact string matches if the whole phrase matches and not if the word is contained in the sentence.

df_text should then look as follows:

| col1 | string_match_good | string_match_bad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| i love cats | love |  |
| i hate dogs |  | hate |

I do not want partial string matches, e.g. if col1 says `'i loved cats'`, then I do not want a string match.

I found the following:
`matches = df_text[df_text['col1'].str.contains(fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(df_dictionary)})\b")]` , however this one does not print the matched words (i.e. good or bad) in the string_match columns.

Does anyone have a solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the data structure is not ideal, specifically because your text values are conceptually several values in one (i.e., lists of tokens/words) but pandas works best with one value per cell. Here's how I'd approach it:

1. Explode the strings such that you get one word per cell.

```py
df_text = (
           df_text.col1.str.split() # split into single words
           .explode() # explode them to one word per cell
           .rename_axis("sent_index") # rename the index for later
           .reset_index() # set the sent_index as its own column
           )
```

Intermediary result:

```py
   sent_index  col1
0           0     i
1           0  love
2           0  cats
3           1     i
4           1  hate
5           1  dogs
```

2. Now you can merge `col1` with `df_dictionary`, once for each of the two labels `good` and `bad`:

```py
for label in ["good", "bad"]:
    df_text = df_text.merge(df_dictionary[label], 
                            left_on="col1", 
                            right_on=label, 
                            how="left")
```

Now `df_text` looks like this:

```py
   sent_index  col1  good   bad
0           0     i   NaN   NaN
1           0  love  love   NaN
2           0  cats   NaN   NaN
3           1     i   NaN   NaN
4           1  hate   NaN  hate
5           1  dogs   NaN   NaN
```

AFAICT, this should already contain all the information you need.

3. Re-combine the words into sentences, using the `sent_index` we set earlier.

```py
df_final = (df_text.groupby("sent_index")
            .agg(list)
            .applymap(lambda s: ' '.join(w for w in s if not pd.isna(w)))
           )
```

The final result then is:

```py
                   col1  good   bad
sent_index                         
0           i love cats  love      
1           i hate dogs        hate
```

Note that in case of multiple matches, you'd get the labels as joined strings, too. E.g., `I dislike dogs but don't hate them` would occur as `'dislike hate'` in the `bad` column. Whether or not that's alright depends on your next steps. Note that this is no problem for the data structure in step 2.